# What languages / countries do not have a dedicated Scrabble set?

Tags: scrabble

There are, obviously, different Scrabble sets for other countries with different letters and - I assume - alphabets. I also assume the letter breakdowns (and point values?) differ - letter commonality may not be the same between languages.

But are there any (major) languages that don't have a set? I don't know if Chinese has a phonetic alphabet in addition to kanji, so I can't imagine they could have one if they don't.

Comment: Please ask that side question separately. It's a valid question, but functionally unrelated to what you're asking here as far as answering goes.

Comment: @VBartilucci :Scrabble and Mattel are the joint owners of the copyright for Scrabble. https://www.zdnet.com/article/scrabble-ownership-and-the-public-domain  You could simply find out how in how many languages they publish the game.

Comment: @Vbartilucci : Kanji is a Japanese writing system borrowed from the Chinese but the Chinese do not call it Kanji. Their phonetic writing system is called «Bopomofo» https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bopomofo

Answer (score 3):

In 2008, there were 29 versions in different languages according to [The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/3776732/Scrabble-60-facts-for-its-60th-birthday.html)

The Boardgame Geek database includes 26 language versions (see the pulldown for languages [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/320/scrabble/versions)). That list doesn't include Chinese.

However: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions) has a breakdown of most (all) language versions (including Chinese language version Zhuyin).

Comment: Some supplementary data: out of the top ten [most spoken languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers), only 5/10 have their own Scrabble version.  There isn't one for Mandarin, Hindi, Arabic, Bengali, or Punjabi.

Comment: I'll also note that the 29 figure might include multiples under each language. e.g., both the French-Canadian and the French versions are listed under French on BGG, while it could be that the Telegraph source counted them separately.

Comment: I am dying to know what the letter breakdown is for the Welsh set. Soooo many consonants...

Comment: Well I'm glad you asked. In researching, I found Wiki has a more complete answer than I initially gave. Welsh tile distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions#Welsh

Comment: I've updated my answer with the wiki information.